# How to select characters before @ in emails for PHP?

Tags: php, email, character, symbols

I'm a newbie in PHP.

I need help selecting only characters before the symbol '@' in email addresses in PHP.

For example;
My email is test@example.com.
 
I only want to return the value 'test', which is characters before the symbol '@'.

I guess this is just a simple question, but I have no idea how to do it.

Help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP has a lot of string funcitons... and [strstr](http://php.net/strstr) is what you want.

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com

$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match('~^(.+)@(.+)$~', $email, $matches)){
    list($email, $before, $after) = $matches;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$pre_at_sign = array_shift(explode('@', $email));
```

Comment: @sectus Only in STRICT mode, few people use that.

Comment: @sectus Has yet to cause me any problems and I have been developing in PHP for 4 years now :)

Answer (score 1):

this will give you characters before @ symbol,

```
$email = 'whatever@email.com';
$exploreArr = explode('@',$email);
echo $exploreArr[0];
```

output will be

```
"whatever"
```